# @Transaction in Spring

Tags: java, spring

If I change the default value of Transaction to `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)`, will the other attributes loose their default values? Do I need to explicitly define the remaining attributes to their default values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, all other default values will remain intact as it is, no change.